# Why aren't my texture packs and mods working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have downloaded 5 texture packs and one mod, I have watched like 10 YouTube videos on how to install them and have done everything according to the video. The texture packs are in the proposed %appdata% files, and when I open up Minecraft I can see them under texture packs, but when I click on them nothing happens. I read somewhere that it could be that Minecraft isn't fully installed, but how do I know if that's true? And then if it isn't, how do I fully install it? And with the mod, I have no idea about anything, so if that could be explained from scratch I would love it. I'm very new to all this texture pack and mod stuff (The technical side of Minecraft). All I usually do is just play the game, so if you could explain it in detail, it would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We don't help with mods. Some texture packs (now resource packs) don't change the menus. Have you tried actually playing the game?

Comment: Did you select the Resource Pack and click the arrow button to move it to the right side of the menu?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about tech support for modded Minecraft.  We only provide tech support for vanilla Minecraft.

Answer (score 3):

For the mods, try downloading and installing [Forge](http://files.minecraftforge.net/). It is a extremely useful tool to mod Minecraft, in fact, most mods require it.

As for the resource packs, it may require you to restart minecraft, if that does not work it might be an outdated texture pack for the version you're running.

And if you bought and installed the game through [minecraft.net](http://minecraft.net), you should have the game fully installed.

Answer (score 0):

- **Mods:** If you want a mod to work you might want to get the latest version of **''Forge''**. It is a great mod launcher. If you have a mod that is NON-FORGE, you still might want to get Forge for it to work better.
- **Texture Packs:** If your resource packs aren't working, you must reboot Minecraft.

Comment: Duplicate answer. The answer posted by Christopher Makin says the same stuff and was posted ~3 hours before this.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend that you go to the file,find META-INF or something like that, delete it and for textures get optifine,and make a folder in .minecraft called shaderpacks, BE SURE TO GET FORGE!!!!